# How to lock database for SELECT query?

Tags: mysql, python

I've a python script that uses SQL Database. I've to process folder sequentially so I've created a 2 column, first one will tell if particular folder is processed or not & second one if it's being processing or not. Now, I've two tmux session that run the python script at same time. Now there is SELECT query inside the py file that check if folder is processing or not. Is there any way such that when one tmux process is doing the SELECT statement to check if folder is processing or not then the process running in another tmux should wait for it. Otherwise both process in tmux will get same value. I tried "BEGIN TRANSACTION" but it's only application for same process. Also when I use LOCK then both the process running inside tmux get LOCKED.

Comment: I am not sure what are you trying to achieve , but it seem that you want table lock for select queries which can be done by using `MyISAM` storage engine. If you could add some real case with table description, some data examples and expected result would be easier to give a proper answer.

Comment: See the "flip-flop" technique described here:  https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table#flip_flop_staging